# Check if an xml section exist in a file using XDocument

Tags: c#, xdoc

I have some code that reads in an xml file. However it is triggering an error at the 3rd IF statement:

```
if (xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default")
    .FirstOrDefault().Descendants("HostID")
    .FirstOrDefault().Descendants("Deployment").Any())
```

Error:

> ```
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> ```

That is because in this particular file there is no `[HOST]` section.

I was assuming that on the first IF statement, if it didn't find any `[HOST]`section it would not go into the statement and therefore i should not get this error. Is there a way to check if a section exists first?

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(myXmlFile);

if (xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Any())
{
    if (xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default").Any())
    {
        if (xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("HostID").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("Deployment").Any())
        {
            if (xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("HostID").Any())
            {
                var hopsTempplateDeployment = xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("HostID").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("Deployment").FirstOrDefault();
                deploymentKind = hopsTempplateDeployment.Attribute("DeploymentKind");
                host = hopsTempplateDeployment.Attribute("HostName");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes instead of Any() you need to use Count() > 0.  Any gives an error if you have a null object.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that.

Comment: @jdweng: Never use `Count() > 0` in place of `Any()`. On long list you will get a measurable perofrmance impact. And it won't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the body of this `if` block...

```
if (xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default").Any())
{
    if (xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("HostID").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("Deployment").Any())
    {
        if (xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("HostID").Any())
        {
            var hopsTempplateDeployment = xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("HostID").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("Deployment").FirstOrDefault();
            deploymentKind = hopsTempplateDeployment.Attribute("DeploymentKind");
            host = hopsTempplateDeployment.Attribute("HostName");
        }
    }
}
```

...you have established that the element `<Root>/HOST/Default` exists. You however *don't* know whether `<Root>/HOST/Default/HostId/Deployment` exists. If it doesn't you will get a `NullReferenceException` like the one you're experiencing due to the use of `FirstOrDefault`. It is generally recommended to use `First` in cases where you expect the elements to be present, which will give you at least a better error message.

If you expect the elements to be not present, a simple solution is to use the `?.` along the respective LINQ2XML axis:

```
var hopsTemplateDeployment =
    xdoc.Root.Descendants("HOST").Descendants("Default").FirstOrDefault()
    ?.Descendants("HostID").FirstOrDefault()
    ?.Descendants("Deployment").FirstOrDefault();
if (hopsTemplateDeployment != null)
{
    deploymentKind = hopsTemplateDeployment.Attribute("DeploymentKind");
    host = hopsTemplateDeployment.Attribute("HostName");
}
```

It will also save you the chain of nested `if` clauses.